# symfony2 how to print server's bug somewhere

Tags: php, symfony

I am running a PHP server. It works like an API (receive http request and send http response to my front end). 
I use symfony2 to help me to develop.

My problem is when my front end requests the back end (so the PHP server). API bugs, send http 500 error, but does not show the error message. So I can't find the error

I use PhpStorm to write code.

I launch my server with `php app/console server:run --env=dev`

Does anyone know how to print the server's error somewhere (in console or in file for example) ?

request from front end : `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/kernel/user`

function which use request in back end `

```
public function postPersist(User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $user->setFullName($user->getFirstName() . ' ' . $user->getLastName());
        $userPositions = $user->getPositions();
        if (isset($userPositions)) {
            foreach ($userPositions as $userPosition) {
                if ($userPosition->isMain()) {
                    $user->setMainPosition($userPosition->getPosition());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $this->setMemberships($user);
        try {
            $this->myFunction($user);//This function has a error. I want to see this error. If I commente this line, it works, so the error come from this function
        }catch(Exception $exception){
            print ($exception->getMessage());
        }
    }`
```

Comment: are you using a try/catch? if so, the Exception will do that with $exception->getMessage()

Comment: I use a try/catch, however, when I write `try {
            $this->nameFunction();
        }catch(Exception $exception){
            print ($exception->getMessage());
        }`
, I have no message in my console

Comment: I think we will need to see some code. This is way too vague. Also check the server error logs.

Comment: Do you know where are the server error logs ?

Comment: Depends on the OS and server, assuming Apache, Fedora family is /var/log/httpd/error.log and Debian family should be /var/log/apache2/error_log

Answer (score 0):

The logs from symfony server are in /app/logs/dev.log